# Pre-populating HTML forms within python CGI

Tags: python, html, cgi

I have been working on a URL parser for the get method when writing CGI scripts in python 2.7. Moving forward I am trying to have my HTML forms pre-populate with either nothing (if the webpage has been just opened) or with what the user entered previously. The script links to itself so everything is being called correctly, I just can't seem to get my python variables where I want them.

```
print "Content-Type: text/html"                                                                                        

print """                                                                                                              
<html>                                                                                                                 
<head>                                                                                                                 
<title> Output from CGI </title>                                                                                       
</head>                                                                                                                

<body>                                                                                                                 
<h3> Creating HTML forms </h3>                                                                                         
<p> Please randomize input below... </p>                                                                               

"""                                                                                                                    
print '<form action="proj1.cgi" method="get">'                                                                         

print '<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="1" />'                                                                 
if f:                                                                                                                  
       print '<input type="text" name="text1" value="'+ html_encode(var['text1'])+'" />'                              
else:                                                                                                                  
       print '<input type="text" name="text1" />'                                                                     

print """                                                                                                              
<input type="submit" />                                                                                                

</form>                                                                                                                


<h3> This was your output: </h3>                                                                                       
<p>                                                                                                                    
"""                                                                                                                    
print 'User Text: %s <br />' %(html_encode(var['text1']))                                                              

if 'cb1' not in var.keys():                                                                                            
       print 'The checkbox wasn\'t checked :(<br />'                                                                  
else:                                                                                                                  
       print 'The checkbox was checked!<br />'                                                                        

print """                                                                                                              
</p>                                                                                                                   
<br /><br />                                                                                                           
</body>                                                                                                                
</html>                                                                                                                
"""
```

I know my formatting is terrible, but I can worry about that once it is working. Those if statements are just checking for data and making decisions based on said data. the trouble explicitly comes in when trying to use python variables in my print statements. I have left off all the other code as not to confuse anyone, but it should be known this is sitting at the bottom of my CGI script rather than being an independent html file.

Comment: Just a heads up, you might want to use JavaScript instead of Python for something like this. If you're insistent on using Python, check out Django or Flask - they make HTML rendering much easier.

Comment: I am actually moving to flask soon after finishing this project. My boss is having me learn the under belly of how the internet works which is why I had to develop my own URL parser for both get and post methods. this is one of the final pieces to this project before moving to a more efficient tool.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. A combination of using a bad test case for my if statements as well as incorrect quoting. If anyone is interested I can post the full code up for reference.